# How do I cast fetched CoreData for upload to Azure Mobile Services?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, azure-mobile-services

I'm new to swift and trying to upload some CoreData to Azure. I know that the CoreData part of the app is working correctly and that the azure upload is working correctly. I've tested them both independently. I'm running into trouble sending my fetchedEvent to Azure. I think it is related to the forced down casting.

Here's my code:

```
@IBAction func sync(sender: UIButton) {
    let client = AppDelegate().client   //reference to the Azure client
    let itemTable:MSTable = client.tableWithName("Events")//create a local Azure table to use in upload

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Events")//create a new fetch request that fetches all information in Events
    do {
        let fetchedEvents = try self.managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as! [NSManagedObject]
        let itemToInsert:NSDictionary = ["buttonColor": fetchedEvents.buttonColor, "eventTime": fetchedEvents.eventTime]    //need to insert the buttonColor and eventTime atributes from the fetched CoreData
        itemTable.insert(itemToInsert as! [NSObject : AnyObject],   //send itemToInsert to azure
                         completion: {
                            insertedItem, error in
                            if (error != nil){
                                print("error: \(error)")
                            }
                            else{
                                print("Success!")
                            }
            }
        )
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not fetch \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
}
```

Should I be down casting the fetchedEvents as something other than a NSManagedObject?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Core Data with Mobile Services, you should consider the offline sync feature that uses Core Data directly. See [Get Started with Offline Data Sync in Mobile Services](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-ios-get-started-offline-data/).

Otherwise, you'll have to convert between dictionaries and Core Data objects which creates much more of a headache. In the case of MSTable.insert, you need to pass an NSDictionary, not NSManagedObject. See https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-ios-how-to-use-client-library/#inserting.